# JavaSamplerClient as springboot with REST. Endpoint unavailable

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter

Through JavaSamplerClient, I need to expose a REST-Endpoint in the JMeter scope and test the signal to be received by that particular REST-Endpoint. I have developed a spring-boot application based on JavaSamplerClient and it can be run in JMeter TestPlan as an intermediate step. Unfortunately, I can't access my endpoint through either Postman or curl. I found out that when my microservice is running, the right port is not open. It looks like the microservice is running in a JMeter container or VM (I don't know).

You can take a look at the implementation:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:oduv/jmeter-sse.git
git clone https://gitlab.com/oduv/jmeter-sse.git
```

the JMуtertest is in src/resource/jmeter folder

please give me an idea on how to open the ports or if any.

**UPD: sorry, I just rebased the source into "master". It was in the "springboot" branch.**

best regards
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see any "REST endpoint" exposed by your "application"

```
package com.nttdata.sse;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JmeterSseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JmeterSseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is just an empty Spring Boot command-line app if I'm reading the [correct branch](https://gitlab.com/oduv/jmeter-sse/-/blob/fat-jar/src/main/java/com/nttdata/sse/JmeterSseApplication.java?ref_type=heads)

If you want to continue with Spring Boot command line application I would suggest:

1. Compiling it into an [executable jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)
2. Start it using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
3. Call the "REST endpoint" (once you implement it) from "normal" Thread Group when/where required
4. Stop the application in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) once your test is done

If you want to run an "endpoint" in JMeter you can just do it using a suitable JSR223 Test Element and [few lines of Groovy code](https://gist.github.com/renatoathaydes/8ad276cedd515f8ff5fc), there is no need to bring the whole Spring Boot beast there, moreover it will be quite tricky to initialize it properly inside JMeter sampler:

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer
int PORT = 8080
HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(PORT), /*max backlog*/ 0).with {
    println "Server is listening on ${PORT}, hit Ctrl+C to exit."    
    createContext("/") { http ->
        http.responseHeaders.add("Content-type", "text/plain")
        http.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0)
        http.responseBody.withWriter { out ->
            out << "Hello ${http.remoteAddress.hostName}!\n"
        }
        println "Hit from Host: ${http.remoteAddress.hostName} on port: ${http.remoteAddress.holder.port}"
    }
    start()
}
```

Comment: I am VERY sorry @Dimitri, I have merged the changes now into master branch